# How to Firing VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new with vuejs, in this case I to try implement scrolling indicator with vuejs

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body id="app">
        <indicator></indicator>
      <main>Ut deserunt mollit ham, sunt exercitation veniam reprehenderit commodo. Ullamco chicken andouille t-bone in. Pork nulla spare ribs reprehenderit chicken alcatra sed, bacon meatball pork belly pork chop kielbasa prosciutto. Sunt jerky excepteur cupim sirloin laborum tempor pork cillum turkey porchetta ipsum dolore. Short ribs leberkas velit voluptate ham ham hock. Occaecat sirloin tongue andouille corned beef bacon capicola sausage, ullamco pork tail incididunt. Officia turducken meatloaf duis dolore pig aute enim kevin rump. In culpa eiusmod aliquip chicken pariatur rump quis. Qui adipisicing nostrud t-bone cupim, shoulder cillum velit. Magna tri-tip sausage, do incididunt brisket ham capicola leberkas consectetur. Elit pork chop kevin, pork belly do jowl fugiat. Fugiat beef tail bresaola pork loin venison short ribs meatloaf veniam nulla commodo flank. Hamburger eu velit shank. Commodo pork chop est et anim ball tip pancetta qui pig. Tail eu pancetta tempor, ex id nulla esse spare ribs nostrud. Jerky cow ea chicken, strip steak nisi swine jowl do. Strip steak beef ribs aliquip hamburger jowl bacon shankle prosciutto et dolore tri-tip pastrami sausage. Pig magna hamburger, irure brisket pork loin aliqua nulla kevin tongue qui aliquip ham. Dolore commodo boudin spare ribs occaecat. Corned beef laborum prosciutto</main>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
   <script>
   Vue.component('indicator', {
  template:'<div id="indicator"></div>',
  mounted:function(){
    var vm = this
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
      var scrollPos = window.scrollY
      var winHeight = window.innerHeight
      var docHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight
      var perc = 100 * scrollPos / (docHeight - winHeight)
      vm.$el.style.width = perc + '%'
    })
  }
})
new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
   </script>
  
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is my code doesn't firing at all. Not sure what to do with the code.

Anyway how to firing vue in the correct way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one major flaw in your code which makes it not work. Eventhough you create the component, you never mount it to the actual HTML. Below the `Vue.component({...})` add this line:

```
new Vue({ el: '#app' });
```

This will mount the Vue instance to the element with ID `app`. However this brings another problem.

Vue doesn't allow you to mount to a `html` or `body` tag. You'll have to encase all the HTML in the body in a div (or other element) and give that the ID `app`

Comment: Devils in detail, the code woks like a a charm after I move `#app` into another element

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Vue root instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

If you leave this, nothing will bind to your app container. Besides you should not directly bind to the `body` tag and instead create a new empty `div` inside the `body` and give it the id `app`.

Edit: Be sure to watch "Why Vue.js" on the official page https://vuejs.org